# TEMPDB Log Files

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, tempdb

Do I want to store the `tempdb` log files on the same drive as my user database log files, the same drive as the `tempdb` data file, or on a separate drive?

Comment: If you have enough distinct disks/LUNs available, then I'd say: get your TempDB on separate disk/LUN, with data files on a disk/LUN and log file on a separate disk/LUN. This presentation - http://sqlbits.com/(S(ckin5tat3ut34q55gkgc32eo))/Sessions/Event5/Designing_I_O_systems_for_SQL_Server - will be of help, I'm sure.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7009/sql-server-tempdb-data-log-file-placement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how many disks you have available, how active your databases are going to be, and how much data work tempDB will see. In our environments we put tempDB on its own disk and size it out, with the log file lumped in with the user log files and have not had any issues. Of course, monitor for contention and keep an eye on everything. Here are some links for further reading:

[Brent Ozar disk reading](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/02/when-should-you-put-data-and-logs-on-the-same-drive/)

[TempDB best practice by people smarter than me](http://www.confio.com/logicalread/sql-server-tempdb-best-practices-placement-w01/#.Uuhe3RDnZhE)

[SQL Server Central forum chat](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1340755-1550-1.aspx)